# Separating rendered objects in layers for Photoshop?

Tags: rendering

I want my rendered objects in separate layers so that i can take them in photoshop and add stuff in between. How do I do that? One way I learned was hide other objects and use *Transparent* in *Render Properties>Film>Transparent* but this method doesnot render bounce lights. What I need is an entire scene rendered as usual but the objects separated in different layers. * phew *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cryptomatte masks can be used. There is this [EXR-IO add-on for Photoshop](https://www.exr-io.com/) that lets you import Multilayer EXR files with Cryptomatte masks.

Rendering simple [render layers(View Layers)](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/introduction.html#view-layers) is also an option. You create new layers and choose what collections to include, exclude or mask in the Outliner:
[image]

You can also control which ones to render:

[image]

That's animatable.

Note that if you use compositing, Render Layers node has an option to choose the layer:

[image]

It's animatable property as well so you can output some layers for some frame ranges and others for other frame ranges.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/view_layer.html

You can hide objects from a layer, but leave their shadows and reflections in tact as well:

[image]

Comment: Photoshop is not the best tool to do compositing though. Compositing in 32 bits can be done in Blender. That would make things easier with color management. Other way if you use EXRs in Photoshop you will need to do color grading in Photoshop. Which is very similar experience to chewing broken glass if you asked me...

Comment: But won't layers disable the bounce lights too from the disabled objects?

Comment: It depends on what you are after. You can mask the object, exclude it , or leave it's light bounces and shadows only. See updated answer.

Comment: OH that's neat. I will try this, and maybe this is what i am after.

Comment: I just tried this and this is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One solution I have is to enable Cryptomatte passing in "View layer properties". Watch a youtube video on this matter!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OykO2GkSyUo

Comment: I feel cryptomatte is the make do way for the moment, thanks,.